# Numbering diagrams in a proof

Tags: numbering, diagrams

I am writing a paper and am having trouble numbering my diagrams. A good example is the situation:

```
The Riemann Zeta function is defined as
\[\zeta(s) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s}\]
```

However, I also want a number for the line on the right of selected diagrams and can't figure out the code. The best example I can find is using tag, but I can't get it to work properly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We need to know what actual code you're using now. You are not writing `The Riemann Zeta function is defined as [\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s}]`; that wouldn't compile because there is no command there to enter math mode. If you use `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` to enter/leave math mode, you should get numbers, for example. Also, your example is not what I would call a "diagram", just an equation. Might be a language issue.

Comment: Change `\[` into `\begin{equation}` and `\]` into `\end{equation}`.